# Why is DisplayForModel not showing the expected output?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple razor page, where the first part correctly shows information from each element in my model in a table.  After that I'm trying to use DisplayFor to show me every property in the model, but it generates **123** for each iteration.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@model System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<DBFramework.MyPerson>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<p></p>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:300px;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:300px;">Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var p in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label(p.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(p.Age.ToString())</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@foreach (DBFramework.MyPerson x in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel(x)<br/>
}
```

Creates the following output:

```
Name  Age
Mike  40 
Penny  1 
Kunal  30 

123
123
123
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayFor` and `DisplayForModel` are used with templates in Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates.

When you call `DisplayForModel`, it will take the page model (Model) and if you specify a parameter, will try to load the template with the name provided (if string) or add the object as additional data in `ViewData`. When you called:

```
@foreach (DBFramework.MyPerson x in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel(x)<br/>
}
```

You told it - Display `Model` which is type `System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<DBFramework.MyPerson>` and add `MyPerson` in the template `ViewData`. Do this 3 times. You also didn't give him a hint to select a DisplayTemplate and it will try to use convention to find it.

As Bappi Datta said, if you want to display a template for `MyPerson`, you need to call:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
}
```

However, you need a `MyPerson` display template created which accepts `@model DBFramework.MyPerson` to render the item or it will simply do a .ToString() by default I believe.